# Размер шрифта от длины значения

Tags: css

Как при значении в длину 5 цифр (10000) установить `font-size` в `12px` без скриптов?

```css
body { background: #F0F4F8; }

span {
  width: 32px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 17px;
  display: block;
  background: #64bef0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:before {
  content: attr(value);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span value='1000' onclick=
  'this.setAttribute("value", this.getAttribute("value") == 1000 ? 10000 : 1000)'>
</span>
```

Comment: Боюсь, что только css никак, у него рабочая единица это тег, а не текст

Comment: @AlexeyTen, угу, костыляндия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось сделать только при помощи *input*, с регулярным выражением в атрибуте *pattern*, где длина значения становится валидным при 5 и более цифр.

Однако, при атрибуте *disabled* или *readonly* псевдокласс *:valid* не работает.

Помог `pointer-events: none;`, но перестал работать `cursor: pointer;` и если добавить событие *onclick* в *input* или обернуть его в *label*, выделение начинает работать

```js
function set(value) { document.querySelector('input').value = value; }
```

```css
input {
    width: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #64bef0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;

    pointer-events: none;
        cursor: pointer; /* ( ◡́.◡̀) */
}

input:valid { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<input value='10000' pattern='\d{5,}' tabindex='-1'>

<br><br>
<button onclick='set(1000)'>1000</button>
<button onclick='set(10000)'>10000</button>
```

Comment: Вот это извращение. Но до вашего инпута можно с клавиатуры добраться, наверное

Comment: @AlexeyTen, действительно, табом добрался :(

Comment: Можно попробовать отрицательный tabindex задать

Comment: @AlexeyTen, точно, спасибо