# Responsive İnput

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы размер `input` соответствовал тому, что внутри него?
То есть, если число достигло 100, то `input` расширяется.

Неважно как это будет сделано - через *CSS* или *JS*.

Тут идет речь об **input type="number"** Не путайте с другими вопросами.

```css
input
{
width:30px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
{ 
opacity:1;
}

span
{
  padding:2px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="10" />
<br>
Пример:<br>
<span class="10">10</span><br><br>
<span class="100">100</span>
```

Comment: Может [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545303) что похожее, если нужно без js. На js сделать расплюнуть

Comment: Это вообщем не то.Тут идет речь об type="number"

Comment: Ну да, у number `pattern` не работает

Comment: Что-то вот такое http://jsfiddle.net/m2vgawkk/12/ по мотивам вопроса https://toster.ru/q/222136

Comment: @Visman, Да то что надо http://jsfiddle.net/m2vgawkk/14/ , спасибо!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение на js

```css
input { width: 32px; }
```

```html
<input type='number' value='99' oninput='style.width = (value.length * 7 + 20) + "px"'>
```

Comment: При смене шрифта, необходимо изменять константы. Да и со знаком - возникает проблема.

Comment: @PetrChalov, да, хватит лишь 7 изменить на размер, равный одному символу цифре у шрифта

Comment: _размер, равный одному символу цифре у шрифта_ - ширина цифр может быть разной

Comment: @Grundy, может, но про шрифт в вопросе ничего не сказано

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, при вводе вставлять весь текст в скрытый контейнер, брать его ширину и прописывать в стили к полю ввода.

```js
var number = document.querySelector('input'),
 box = document.querySelector('span');

number.oninput = function(){
 this.style.width = 15 + getTextWidth(this.value) + 'px';
}

function getTextWidth(text){
 box.innerHTML = text;
  return box.offsetWidth;
}
```

```css
input {
  min-width:30px;
  font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
}

span {
  font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
<span></span>
```

Comment: Каждый пример имеет право на жизнь)